# Is there a difference between global Initialization vs viewDidLoad initialization in Swift

Tags: swift, scope, initialization, viewdidload

If I have a class and initialize a variable like so:

```
class TestClass: UIViewController {
    var thisInt: Int = 10
}
```

is that any different than initializing like so:

```
class TestClass: UIViewController {
    var thisInt: Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        thisInt = 10
    }
}
```

I suppose my main questions lie in when the global initialization takes place, and is there a time when one would get called more than the other would be called with normal iOS Programming (not doing anything drastically against native development). I do understand that doing it in viewDidLoad restricts me to using weak or an optional, but I'm more concerned about any other differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out easily by adding a "computed" property to your view controller:

```
class TestClass: UIViewController {
    let a = {()->Int in print("global initialization"); return 10 }()
}
```

and adding a

```
print("didFinishLaunching")
```

in app's delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

The order you'll get is

```
global initialization
didFinishLaunching
```

which means global initializers run before the app lifecycle begins.

Now, to go even further, you could add a `main.swift` file with the following contents

```
print("Before UIApplicationMain")

UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, unsafeBitCast(CommandLine.unsafeArgv, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>.self), nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self))
```

and remove (or comment) the `@UIApplicationMain` decoration from your AppDelegate class. This will instruct the compiler to use the code in `main.swift` for the application initialization instead of the default behavior provided by the decorator in discussion (although we're providing a custom almost identical implementation).

What you'll get in this 2nd approach is

```
Before UIApplicationMain
global initialization
didFinishLaunching
```

which means that the instance property code is executed when the storyboard is loaded.

Now, for more insight, let's try to find out the differences between static an instance variables. For this we'll add a test class:

```
class PropertyInitializationTest {
    static let staticProp = {()->String in print("static initialization of InitializationTest"); return "" }()
    let instanceProp = {()->String in print("instance initialization of InitializationTest"); return "" }()

    init() {
        print("In initializer")
    }
}
```

, and update AppDelegate's did finish launching:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        print("didFinishLaunching")
        print("before instantiating InitializationTest")
        _ = PropertyInitializationTest()
        print("after instantiating InitializationTest")
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

The output we get is:

```
Before UIApplicationMain
global initialization
didFinishLaunching
before instantiating InitializationTest
instance initialization of InitializationTest
In initializer
after instantiating InitializationTest
```

, which confirms the fact that instance properties get set when the class is instantiated, and before any initializer code runs.

But wait! What about the static property? There are no traces to indicate that it was initialized at all. Looks like static properties are lazy by definition, and get initialized only when accessed the first time.

Updating the app did finish launching code confirms this.

```
print("didFinishLaunching")
print("before instantiating InitializationTest")
_ = PropertyInitializationTest()
print("after instantiating InitializationTest")
_ = PropertyInitializationTest.staticProp
print("after instantiating InitializationTest")
```

gives the following output:

```
Before UIApplicationMain
global initialization
didFinishLaunching
before instantiating InitializationTest
instance initialization of InitializationTest
In initializer
after instantiating InitializationTest
static initialization of InitializationTest
after instantiating InitializationTest
```

To conclude:

- instance properties receive the compile-time values (if set) before the class initializer runs, thus before any code from that class gets executed
- static properties receive their values only when firstly accessed, they are lazy by nature

Comment: Great Answer!!! So, that answers half my question. The other half, Is there ever a time that global initialization would be triggered without viewDidLoad or viewDidLoad would without global initialization of the class they are in? This is assuming that it does not crash in the middle of global initialization.

Comment: @Sethmr I updated my answer with more results. The conclusion is that the `viewDidLoad` code will always run after the global initialization, as this is part of the setup the runtime does when instantiating a class

Comment: Thanks for your time. I can dig into stuff like this, but hearing it from someone with a deeper understanding makes it so much easier to grow and see the best way to figure these things out in the future.

Comment: The one question this leaves me with is... How does it know how many times the class with the global variable will be called in order to initialize it's data for each instantiation of the class?

Comment: The runtime doesn't have to know how many instances it will get created. There is code in place created by the compiler for the property initialization, and that code gets executed by the runtime when an class is instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are differences. Although both of your examples would technically work and your first snippet is the most common.

I'll show you one example, when you actually need to implement it as described in your second snippet:

```
class ImageDisplayingViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var thumbImageView: UIImageView!

    var choosenImageTag: Int!
    var choosenImage: UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        thumbImageView.tag = imageTag
        thumbImageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Let's say you have a view controller where you choose an image and then navigate to the next view controller to display this image (and a tag, so to keep Int as in your example). You would pass that image and the tag in the `prepare(for segue:, sender:)` by calling:

```
destinationViewController.choosenImage = choosenImage
destinationViewController.choosenImageTag = 10
```

Then the `ImageDisplayingViewController` will actually load the image in the `viewDidLoad()` method, where you're sure that your outlets have been initialised.

If you were about to just try and load the image directly in the `prepare(for segue:, sender:)` method you would get a crash, as outlets were not initialised yet.

```
destinationViewController.thumbImageView.image = choosenImage  // crash
destinationViewController.thumbImageView.tag = 10
```

Comment: I appreciate your time, so you get a vote. I was looking for information more focussed on when the first example is initialized, and if there is ever a circumstance when if you had both methods going with different variables that one variable could be initialized again and the other would not be called.

Comment: I have been working as an iOS Developer for over a year now and am feeling like I can program almost anything at this point. It seems like all of the questions I do have for stack overflow are quite different and not answered as I want them to be. The kinds of questions most people ask I feel show a lack of research 95%+ of the time.